# renewcommand of variable inside package's function

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I am using the tikz based [neuralnetwork](https://github.com/battlesnake/neural/blob/master/neuralnetwork.sty) library and I am trying to change the variable `nnlinklabelextrastyle` to modify the font of of the edge labels, but I can't figure out how to target `nnlinklabelextrastyle` with the `renewcommand` or how to go about looking for a solution, terminology wise, in case the way I am trying to do it is all wrong.

Edit: Here is a minimal examples that produces a neural network image but the text is too big. I am trying to make it smaller by changing the font style. Also there are some error when running the example but I cannot figure out how to fix it from the error message, although I think I am missing a package definition or something similar...

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{neuralnetwork}


\begin{document}
\begin{neuralnetwork} [nodespacing=12mm, layerspacing=45mm,
            maintitleheight=2.5em, layertitleheight=2.5em,
            height=5, toprow=false, nodesize=30pt, style={},
            titlestyle={}]
%\newcommand\nnlinklabelextrastyle{font=\small}  %<-- failed attempt
\newcommand{\linklabelsU}[4]{Error wrt $w_{#4,#2}^#3$}
\inputlayer[count=3, bias=false]
\hiddenlayer[count=4, bias=false]
\link[style={thick, color=red}, from layer=1, to layer=0, from node=1, to node=1, label=\linklabelsU]
\outputlayer[count=1]
\link[style={thick, color=red}, from layer=2, to layer=1, from node=1, to node=1, label=\linklabelsU]
\link[style={thick, color=red}, from layer=2, to layer=1, from node=1, to node=2, label=\linklabelsU]
\link[style={thick, color=red}, from layer=2, to layer=1, from node=1, to node=3, label=\linklabelsU]
\link[style={thick, color=red}, from layer=2, to layer=1, from node=1, to node=4, label=\linklabelsU]
\end{neuralnetwork}
\end{document}
```

[image: Backpropagation of neural net]

Comment: you don't do renewcommand to pgfkeys based `/.style` options.

Comment: Please provide a Minimal Working Example. So others can help you

Comment: If anyone understand what I am trying to do and has a better title in mind, please don't hesitate and edit it, because I think it is not very descriptive.

Comment: @percusse `nnlinklabelextrastyle` is not a style key, it's a macro that is `\def`ed in the package code.

Comment: @PaulGessler Really? Oh my. I would stay away from that probably.

Comment: @percusse yep, my thoughts exactly! :-)

Comment: @PaulGessler But it looks like there is not much complication to convert it to a style as it is simply a replacement. It's just around 300 lines of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the author defined the options using `xkeyval` inside the TikZ key declarations. My guess is that he/she wanted to mimic the TikZ syntax without the tedious TikZ parser hacking.

Hence to be able to make the keys seen by the TikZ parser, the author used `\edef` on the macros. But that trips when TeX tries to expand `\small` and so on.

If you really need this package, then I would suggest converting things to `pgfkeys` once and for all and make a pull request on Github.